# Reflection performance in Java or Spring

Tags: spring, reflection, interface

I'm transferring an old service written in Java to Spring. I noticed a significant drop in performance.I've identified that this code is responsible for it.The code below is called tens of thousands of times for objects.

```html
Object helper = Class.forName(helperConfig.get(0)).newInstance();
((FieldHelperInterface) helper).setConnection(connection);
Method method = helper.getClass().getMethod(helperConfig.get(1), ResultSet.class);
value = method.invoke(helper, resultSet);
```

I know reflection is less efficient than direct calling, but why only after transferring to Spring?
How to improve it?
How to inject Spring "HelperInterface" components and call the methods indicated by their names?

Comment: A full method, a full class and some context can help a lot to answer.